# Access Named Credentials with merge fields

Tags: apex, exception, namedcredentials, apex-webservice

I am on a task where I need to call an external webservice that takes the username and password in the request body, not as part of Authorization header. I did setup the username and password using Named Credentials, but I am having trouble accessing the actual username and password from the named credentials as merge fields.

Below is my setup

```
Identity Type : Named Principal
Authentication Protocol : Password Authentication
Username : {Service Account Username}
Password : {Service Account Password}

Generate Authorization Header : Unchecked
Allow merge fields in HTTP Header : Unchecked
Allow merge fields in HTTP Body : Checked
```

I tried various options, but nothing seems to work. When I access the named credential via code using the merge fields {!$Credential.Username} and {!$Credential.Password} and assigning them to string variables, the debug log is only printing {!$Credential.Username} and {!$Credential.Password} only and not the actual username and password.

Apparently, the HTTP send is throwing a ScriptThrownException when I make a callout to the external webservice with the above credentials.

Also, if I have multiple named credentials in my salesforce org, how do I access the correct one using merge fields?

Can someone help?

Comment: Thanks for your response. So, it seems like we cannot see the username and password in the debug logs, which is okay. However, I am not sure why I am getting a ScriptThrownException. My org already has a named credential that everyone in our teams are using it where "Generate Authorization Header" is checked. So, I created a new named credential for this external service. I am assuming that salesforce is pulling the credentials from the first one. Is there a way for me to have salesforce pickup the credentials from the new one that I created?

Comment: The name of the Naming Credential is unique, you use that name when you call out to the external service.

Comment: How are you specifying the endpoint for the HTTP request?
How are you using the merge fields in the body of the request?
Maybe you can share your Apex code where you create the HTTP request that specifies the endpoint and shows how you are building the request body with the credential merge fields? The endpoint is how you will select which specific Named Crediental to use.

Comment: Figured out the issue. It was a complicated setup in our case. The external service was setup in other system's QA/DEMO environment which can only be called from our salesforce QA/DEMO environment. Since I am still in the process of development, the service call from my individual sandbox did not work. I had to fake as if I am calling from Salesforce QA/DEMO environment and it is working now. Thanks to everyone for your help.